# Sharepoint 2003 Create listing of all visitors across all sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, reports

The director asked me to try to come up with a listing of all sites and how many visits each has had over a specific date range, is that possible?  I found information on finding the number of users, but he is asking for the number of visits.

Has anyone come up with a query that would do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

This depends - you have access to the usage reports if they were configured, but by default I believe they only cover 30 days - and without custom reporting is a tedious excessive as they are scoped to sites. You can view these if you open a site and go into Site Settings.

Two other approaches you can take:
If you have not purged any of the IIS logs - and they are configured to capture users then you can use a tool like LogParser (or PowerShell) to get the data you need. LogParser can take in multiple log files and uses SQL like syntax.

**Edit**
Removed - non-relevant info

Comment: Thank you Jesus - I do not see the Usage and Health Database, do you know if that is a part of Sharepoint 2003?  Google mentions 2013.

Comment: I misread your title - I didn't realize it was 2003.  With 2003 I would go for the IIS logs.